# How to split items into 3 columns by for loop?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, for-loop

How to split items(grids) into 3 columns of a container by for loop

Mine output does not correct as what I want it to be

```
       let array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', and more++];

Let say array will display multiple grid. 


       let rowcount = Math.Ceil(array.length / 3)
       for (let i < 1; i < array.length; i++）{
        return i++;
       }

Mine output:- have 7 length of array , after rowcount will get
a        b        c
d        e        f        g
Wrong... 


Expected Output:-
a        b        c
d        e        f
g      more     more
more   more     more 
more   more     more
more   more     more
more   more     more
more   more     more
more   more     more
more
```

I want to print 3 items into each row else to next row even don't have 3 items (maybe just 1 or 2).
Does someone know about the solution?

Comment: You just want to print 3 items and then go to the next new line?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately your question is a bit vague. What is the array you want to split? What is the expected output? Three arrays? A Html table?

Comment: Very very confused by what you mean. What does your Array look like? Is it multi-dimensional or is it supposed to be chunked...? Please provide what data you have and what it looks like. When you say columns, I can appreciate you formatting your request so it makes sense visually, but we don't know if you mean columns on your page, or in your data?

Comment: To: Michael Platt       Yes

Comment: To: zfrisch  Added

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `ng-repeat` and watching the value of `$index`. Here's a sample using some CSS to apply `float` and `clear` to simulate columns. `ng-repeat` requires unique values so I used `track by` just in case your collection doesn't have a unique identifier.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [];
    for (let i = 65; i < 91; i++) {
      $scope.items.push(String.fromCharCode(i));
    }
  });
```

```css
.column {
  width: 50px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

.last {
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <table>
    <div ng-repeat="item in items track by $index" class="column" ng-class="{ last: $index % 3 === 0 }">
      {{ item }}
    </div>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should cut it:

```js
let rowCount = 3;

// Build temp array for example 
let arr = [...Array(100)].map((e, i) => i);

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += rowCount) {
  // Container to hold current row
  let tmp = [];
  for (let k = 0; k < rowCount; k++) {
    if (i + k === 0) {
      tmp.push(arr[i + k]);
    } else {
      tmp.push(arr[i + k] || 'n/a');
    }
  }
  console.log(tmp);
}
```

Comment: Thanks all, I found that use mod syntax would helps which is total % 3